# No Spring Boot Template when create new Jelastic environment

Tags: spring-boot, jelastic

Trying to deploy my spring boot application to Jelastic.
According to [manual](http://blog.jelastic.com/2017/04/27/hosting-spring-boot-java-applications/) I need to create environment from **SpringBoot** template.
But in my case there is no **SpringBoot** template. What I see is just a list of available application servers: GlassFish, Jetty, Tomcat, etc.
How to get **SpringBoot** template there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the hosters with version of Jelastic starts with 4.10.1 and higher can provide the possibility to host Spring Boot applications. You can find the most suitable cloud provider using filter by version on the [Jelastic Cloud Union](https://jelastic.cloud).

Comment: One point, I couldn't see the option either on my provider, even though they were at version 5. I asked their support staff what the issue was, they fiddled for a moment and then asked me to log out and log in again, and the option appeared. Might be worth a try?